# Proximity device handler only fires once (WP8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, event-handling, nfc

I made a program that handles NFC tags back in 2013, today after two years of pause on that program i continued with it, and ran into some strange problem. In the program i read NFC tags which are writen with a "window.Someid" so they are app specific.

For some reason, the program works perfectly when scanning the NFC tag, except, when i want to scan the tag for the second time, the handler doesn't fire. any idea what causes this? (i see no error message).

Here's my code:

```
        ProximityDevice PDevice;
    private long SubscriptionID = -1;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PDevice = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();

        // subscribe for messages
        SubscriptionID = PDevice.SubscribeForMessage("Windows.SomeMsg", ProximityMessageRcvd);
    }

    private void ProximityMessageRcvd(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Message");
    }
```